# Kafka: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException while creating topic on multi server setup

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I am trying to setup multi node `Kafka-0.8.2.2` cluster with 1 Producer, 1 consumer and 3 brokers all on different machines.

While creating topic on `producer`, I am getting error as `org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids`. Complete console output is available **[here](https://justpaste.it/rvn5)**. There is no error in `Kafka Producer`'s log.

Command I am using to run `Kafka` is:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic edwintest
```

**Note**: Zookeeper service is running on all the servers, and all three brokers are having Kafka servers running on them (*Only Brokers need Kafka Server. **Right?***).

Configuration of my ***producer.properties*** is as:

```
metadata.broker.list=<IP.OF.BROKER.1>:9092,<IP.OF.BROKER.2>:9092,<IP.OF.BROKER.3>:9092

producer.type=sync

compression.codec=none

serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder
```

Below are some of the many articles I was using as reference:

- [Zookeeper & Kafka Install : A single node and a multiple broker cluster - 2016](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Zookeeper_Kafka_single_node_Multiple_broker_cluster.php)
- [Step by Step of Installing Apache Kafka and Communicating with Spark](https://chongyaorobin.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/step-by-step-of-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-standalone-mode/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because I was trying to connect to the `zookeeper` of localhost. My understanding was zookeeper is needed to be running on producer, consumer, and the Kafka brokers, and the communication is done between producer -> broker and broker -> consumer via zookeeper. But that was incorrect. Actually:

> **Zookeeper** and **Kafka** servers should be running only on on broker servers. While creating the topic or publishing the content to the topic, public DNS of any of the Kafka broker should be passed with *--zookeeper* option. There is no need to run Kafka server on producer or consumer instance.

Correct command will be:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper <Public-DNS>:<PORT> --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic edwintest
```

where: *Public-DNS* is the DNS of any of the Kafka broker and *PORT* is the port of the zookeeper service.

Answer (score 1):

At the very first glance it seems like you're calling create topic to a local zookeeper which is not aware of any of your kafka-brookers. You should call  `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper <IP.OF.BROKER.1>:2181`

Comment: I also need one more clarification. `Kafka` server should be running on only brokers? Also `broker.id=x` parameter in `server.properties` is need to be set only for brokers?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri In Kafka terminology Kafka server is called as broker. In Kafka cluster you will have only brokers and they are identified by broker.id which should be distinct positive Integer. Producers and Consumers are not considered as servers they are just clients.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I got the question. Actually the kafka-serves are the broker. The (default) setup looks like this. You a set of kafka-servers (a.k.a.) broker. Beside the broker you have an odd number of zookeeper server which are used to coordinate the server. Furthermore you have clients which are producers (write messages to the server/broker) and cosumer who read messages from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It cleared one of the huge doubt of mine. I need one more clarafication. `zookeeper` is not required on producer and consumer machines?

Comment: You're right. Zookeeper is *not* needed on the client maschines. Just to clearify what zookeeper is used for: 

On the one hand zookeeper is used for coordinating the cluster - each Kafka Broker needs to know what other Brokers are at the cluster, which broker is responsible for which partion of which topic etc. Furthermore the zookeeper servers are used to handle the offsets of your consumer-groups (at least until version 0.8.x on 0.9.x things changed but this is something I cant tell you for sure)

Hope that helps

Comment: I have followed all the steps, but now I am getting `ConnectException` while starting `zookeeper`. I have asked a separate question for that: [Zookeeper-Kafka: ConnectException-Connection Refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768209/zookeeper-kafka-connectexception-connection-refused) . May be you can help me with that.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue I mentioned above. Replacing the `Public IP` with `Public DNS` fixed the issue. A big `Thank You` to both of you. I was trying to set up the Kafka cluster from last 1 week. Finally I am able to do that :D