# Zookeeper -Kafka: ConnectException - Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, ubuntu-14.04, kafka-python

I am trying to setup 3 Kafka brokers on *ubuntu EC2* machines. But I am getting `ConnectException` while starting `zookeeper`. All the ports in the `security group` of my `ec2` intsances are already open.

Below is the stack trace:

```
[2016-03-03 07:37:12,040] ERROR Exception while listening (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:330)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$Listener.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:507)
...
...
...

[2016-03-03 07:23:46,093] WARN Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /52.36.XXX.181:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:840)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:762)
```

Below is the configuration of:

***zookeeper.properties***:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0

server.1=52.37.XX.70:2888:3888
server.2=52.36.XXX.181:2888:3888
server.3=52.37.XX.42:2888:3888
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
```

***server.properties***:

```
broker.id=1
port=9092
host.name=52.37.XX.70

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false

zookeeper.connect=52.37.XX.70:2181,52.36.XXX.181:2181,52.37.XX.42:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

I have added server's public IP in ***/etc/hosts*** of the instances. My modified /etc/hosts is as:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain ip-10-131-X-217
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain 52.37.XX.70
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

The unique `myid` entries in `/tmp/zookeper/myid` are also entered correctly.

I have followed all the steps mentioned in: [How to create a MultiNode - MultiBroker Cluster for Kafka on AWS](https://gist.github.com/mkanchwala/fbfdd5ef866a58a77f6e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was because I was using the `Public IP` of the server. Instead of that, use of `Public DNS` of `ec2` instances fixed the issue.

Comment: why can't you use private ips, which enables faster data exchange between cluster nodes. For example you can benefit faster data replication between kafka nodes through private ips which happens through LAN.